# Verticall Align Two Headers of Different Sizes

Tags: html, css

I simply want to align an H1 and an H2 along the vertical axis.  I would like the options of center, top of text and bottom of text (not sure which one I want to go with yet).

I have tried the following start:

HTML

```
<div>Able was I...</div>
<h1>A man a plan</h1><h2>a canal...Panama!</h2>
<div style="clear:both">ere I saw Elba</div>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
    float:left;    

}
h2
{
    float:left;
}
```

Check out the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzsrkt49/1/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block` instead of floats and use `vertical-align: whatever-you-want`

```
h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;    
}

h2{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;    
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yzsrkt49/2/)